# MYSQL query syntax LEFT JOIN on two tables no data on retrieveing through PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

hello guys i have a problem about my MYSQL syntax Here is my syntax

```
SELECT * FROM products left outer join reviews ON products.p_id = reviews.p_id WHERE products.service_prom = '{$value}' GROUP BY products.p_id  ORDER BY rand() DESC
```

now if product have an a value on second table which is review they retrieving it displaying the full data now if products have not a review the data in not fully retrive like This

Note the product does have a image is not have a problem because they have a data on next table that have same id , 
The product does not have a image and price also rate have a problem because they not have a review on review table

[image: Here is the image example the data have a image is right fully retrieve it means they does not have a problem]

[image: Here is second example]

Here is my table structures and data Which is Product.id "p_id " is equal on review.p_id 
[image: Table of Products]

[image: Table of Reviews of products]

Comment: Your query makes little sense.  You have `SELECT *` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: you mean that select only column on table

Comment: SELECT products.p_available,
    products.p_id,
    products.image1,
    products.p_name,
    products.s_price,
    products.d_price,
    products.service_prom,
    reviews.p_id,
    reviews.star FROM products LEFT JOIN reviews ON  products.p_id = reviews.p_id AND reviews.star  WHERE products.service_prom = '{$value}' GROUP BY products.p_id  ORDER BY rand() DESC